# operator+= yields zero

Tags: c++, operators

[edit]Problem solved - kind of. There never really was a problem. It seems that the debugger was lying to me. Thanks[/edit]

I have a wierd problem that I've been unable to resolve so far. I have a private class member

```
private:
float *_histVals;
```

which is initialized in the constructor as follows:

```
// allocate memory for the histogram bins
size_t hSize = binsPerChan*binsPerChan*binsPerChan;
this->_histVals = new float[ hSize ];
for (size_t i = 0; i < hSize; ++i)
    this->_histVals[i] = 0.0f;
```

later in the program I want to add something to certain array elements in the following way:

```
this->_histVals[ hIndex ] += imgFrac;
```

Here, imgFrac is float value of the magnitude 1.0*e-5 and the current value of the `_histVals[ hIndex ]` Element is zero. However the debugger shows that after the execution of this line the value is still zero.

I suspected a problem with floating point precision but when I try the same thing with a local float variable it works perfectly. So it must have something to do with the array itself. But I've no idea what that possibly could be. I've also checked the index which is within array bounds.

Any suggestions what could cause the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try printing the value? Nobody is perfect, even debuggers aren't.

Comment: Are you building with compiler optimisations enabled?  Have you tried `printf`-ing the value of `this->_histVals[hIndex]` after you do the `+=`?

Comment: If you are working with pointers and have a bug, then you can get weird behavior in all parts of your program.  Could you show us two complete programs, one that demonstrates the bug and the other that demonstrates the correct behavior?  Both should be as simple as possible.  In the process of making these examples you will probably discover what is wrong.

Comment: The debugger may be rounding the value.  The value 1.0E-5 can be considered zero depending on the *displayed* precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::vector<float>` unless you want a difficult life or you're learning how people had to live in the bad old days.

Regarding this having no effect on the array element:

```
this->_histVals[ hIndex ] += imgFrac;
```

Possible causes:

- The debugger is lying to you.
- `imgFrac` is zero

Have you tried logging all the values involved to `std::cout`? Also to convince yourself there's no magic involved, try breaking it down into:

```
float newValue = this->_histVals[ hIndex ] + imgFrac;
this->_histVals[ hIndex ] = newValue;
```

And log the `newValue`.

Comment: My understanding is to prefer `double` to `float`, so the `OP` shoul use `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Depends on the level of precision needed versus the quantity of data you need to store. `long double` is likely to be even more precise than `double` but will therefore take more storage. (Though the standard allows all of them to be the same size and precision).